# How can I change the apiVersion of the Ephemeral Key Provider in Stripe?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I want to create EphemeralKey for my Stripe payment service and I cannot modify the apiVersion of the Stripe.

In my Stripe Dashboard the default apiVersion is `2019-3-14`, but in the Android library keeps the old api Version which is `2017-06-05`. But, it doesn't allow me to modify the value in the `ApiVersion.java` in Stripe Library. How can I override the `EphemeralKeyListener` in order to avoid retrieve the old value?

My code was based on the official examples of Stripe for the SampleStore.

I expect to retrieve the ephemeral key after the rest call the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change this — the stripe-android SDK makes requests directly to the Stripe API, using the ephemeral key you provide. Those requests *must* be [pinned](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning) to a particular version, since the code in the SDK has to be written to work with a specific version(regardless of the version that a user of the SDK might be using) to work properly.

I'm not sure why you want to change the API version used by the SDK — the code in each version of the SDK will only work with the API version it's designed for. Usually you'd just upgrade the SDK itself if there'a specific reason you need to use a more recent API version, but it's not generally required(and it's not a problem if your default version is different from what the SDK uses).

Comment: My SDK version is 2017-06-05 (the old version) but my Stripe Dashboard and the backend developer of my project support the 2019-03-14 (the new /default version). Also, I observed that the last SDK (8.7.0) use also the last version.  So, I think that I am missing something here.

Comment: That's my bad, yeah, both versions use the 2017 version, I'll edit that. Ultimately though, why does it matter? Is it causing a specific issue or error? The SDK has to use a particular version since it could be used by many different Stripe accounts and has to pin a version its code knows how to handle. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Now, understood. I will use the 2017 version in order to be sure.